# UIImageView Image rotation

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have the following code

```
UIImageView *r = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 300)];
r.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testbg"];

[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
r.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg(30));
[UIImageView commitAnimations];

r.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rotbg"];
```

After o rotation I want to change the image in the view but it will be rotated, how can I draw the image without being rotated?

Comment: Well once you've rotated the UIImageView, any image you will add will be rotated. Do you want to move from | to / and then when you change the image display | again?

Comment: i want to add another image which should not be rotated, an preserve the rotation data

Comment: Then I guess you would need to add another image view on top of the current one with the second image so you'll have |/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question properly but I think you can do something like this:

```
UIImageView *r = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 300)];
r.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testbg"];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                 animations:^(){
                     r.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg(30));
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     r.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                     r.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rotbg"];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think this is what you want...

```
UIImageView *r = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 300)];
r.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testbg"];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
 animations:^{
     r.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg(30));
 }

 completion:^(BOOL finished){
           if(finished){
             r.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
             r.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rotbg"];
           }

}];
```

Comment: will this preserve to rotation angle of the UIImageView ? from printinting it out it seems to be preserved , CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0) scares me, tx

Comment: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0) simply says, Hey come back to normal. that's it.